# Execute success ajax from method object via dynamic function

Tags: javascript, oop

I need to run the success of ajax from a method function of object, this work when a pass to normal variable function

```
methodOne = function(data) {
  alert(data);
};

$(document).on('click', ".clichere", function() {
  var callback = function(){};
  callback = methodOne;
  runAjax({dispatch_ajax : "testing"}, callback );
    });

function runAjax(data, succFunction) {

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
      success: succFunction,
      error: function(error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      },
  });

}
```

this not work

```
var myapp = function() {
   this.listTableOptions = function(data) {
    alert(data);
   };
};


$(document).on('click', ".clichere", function() {

  obj = new myapp();

  runAjax({dispatch_ajax : "testing"}, obj.listTableOptions() );

});
```

I can't not get the data in myapp object

Comment: you're calling the function too early - the second argument to `runAjax` should be `obj.listTableOptions` with no parentheses. Compare with your first, working example, where you pass `callback` in without invoking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass the function listTableOptions instead of executing it and passing the result so the following will work:

```
var myapp = function() {
   this.listTableOptions = function(data) {
    alert(data);
   };
};

$(document).on('click', ".clichere", function() {
  obj = new myapp();
  runAjax({dispatch_ajax : "testing"}, obj.listTableOptions );
});
```

Notice `obj.listTableOptions` instead of `obj.listTableOptions()`